# Can't change ringer volume after using soundpool (<2.1)

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

There is a problem, which occured very often.

I am using soundpool to play soundfx. One soundfx "silence.mp3" plays in a loop all the time, so I can change the volume anytime. If I change the volume "media volume" is displayed. It seems it is the volume for the app.

After I leave the app (back or home button) I can't change the "ringer volume".

The sound will play if start the Activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    if (StbApp.mSoundPool != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "playSounds");
        Log.d(TAG, "menu: " + StbApp.menu);
        StbApp.mSoundPool.play(
                StbApp.menu, 
                StbApp.mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 
                StbApp.mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 
                0, 
                0, 
                1
        );
        Log.d(TAG, "menu: " + StbApp.silence);
        StbApp.mSoundPool.play(
                StbApp.silence, 
                StbApp.mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 
                StbApp.mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 
                0, 
                -1, 
                1
        );
    }
```

I try to pause all sounds I use in the app to make sure there are no sound playing for some reason. (Even though it is the launcher activity)

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.gameover);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.execution);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.menu);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.number);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.penalty);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.players);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.quest);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.round);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.spinning);
    StbApp.mSoundPool.pause(StbApp.silence);

    super.onPause();
}
```

I can't use autoPause(), because only API level 8 and higher supports  the method. I try force stop in settings. But this won't work either. I have to restart the phone in order to change the ringer volume. (Sony Ericsson X10)

Is there a way to be able to change the ringer volume after leaving the app in Android 2.1?

EDIT:
I tested it on some more devices. The problem occured on Motorola FlipOut and SE X10 mini as well. It works on Galaxy S, HTC Legends, SE X8 and Galaxy S II.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the "mSoundPool.pause" on the onStop() method instead of onPause().

If it doesn't work, you can try:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

at the end of the onStop().

Comment: I think that somehow your app still "hang" on the audiostream even when not visible. You should check carefully all your "Audio engine" not just the onPause/Resume.

Comment: I tried it in  onStop and in onDestroy as well. I even tried to override finish-method. At the end I release everything. In onResume I have to load the files again. It worked. But still. It is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a silent mp3 to be able to change the volume.  You can put this line in oncreate.

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Information came from here.
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/how-to-tell-android-which-volume-mediaringtone-etc-should-be-controlled-by-your-app/